# Angle bisectors of triangle and related circumcircles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Let the interior and exterior bisectors of the angles of $\triangle ABC$ meet their respective opposite sides in $X$, $Y$, $Z$ and $X'$, $Y'$, $Z'$. Show that the circles $(AXX')$, $(BYY')$, and $(CZZ')$ have 2 common points.

I have shown that the points $X'$, $Y'$, $Z'$ are collinear using Menelaus' theorem, but I can't proceed further. Is inversion a possible method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Hint: These are Apollonian circles. There is a statement and proof in following reference:

College Geometry
An introduction to the modern geometry of the triangle and the circle
Author: Vattan Altshiller Court
ISBN 964-318-222-3

Comment: Thank you for this.I have now proved the result. If two of the circles intersect (as can be shown),then by multiplying together the constants in their respective Appolonian circles you can demonstrate that the third circle passes through the same point.The same argument applies to  the second point of intersection